# How can I find the external IP address of a secure network I can't access?

Tags: ip, network-scanners, ipsec, network-access-control

Is there even a way to do this? I thought you had to be on the network to get information about it. Ideally I don't want to use any sort of phishing/social-engineering attack.

Comment: Networks don't have IP addresses.  Network *nodes*, such as servers or load balancers, have IP addresses.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to gain access to my friend's computer remotely but I don't know what IP address to send the exploit to. He's not running a server but every household has a (more or less) static public IP, right? I figure this IP address is physically located in the ISPs server farm, but isn't this still connected to his router ergo his computer? Naturally, I know the password, I'm just trying to see if it would be possible if I didn't know it. How do I figure out where to send the exploit to?

Comment: It would benefit you to learn a little more about IP networking first. The "server farm" has nothing to do with this. The IP address is allocated to the external interface of each router, each of which has a unique MAC address. The ISP's network has a range of IP addresses that it can assign when the users router logs into the ISP's router (I'm simplifying but that is roughly the process). The ISP has a database of IP addresses matched to MAC addresses so it knows how to route traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily find a specific residential public IP address.

There is no reference for you to use and, in many cases, it will periodically change.

You need a reference of some kind. The ISP has the information because they can relate the users broadband/cable login to an IP address and would also see the MAC address of the external interface of the router (or residential gateway).

You cannot have any of that.

The best you could hope for would be to persuade your friend to visit a website under your control. As long as you knew when they visited or if they have some other form of ID on the site, then you can capture the IP address at that point.